# Spring Boot application with WebSecurity doesn't see css

Tags: css, spring, spring-boot, staticresource, websecurity

I have a webSecConfig class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. I paste it's method where I tried to allow access with using .antMatchers.
My folder structure:
...
-resources
--static    (here I have images for the html/css)
--templates
---login.html
---design.css
I have tried adding a "public" folder based on some comments, but nothing seems to work so far. Can anyone help me with this please?

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/messages", true)
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "GET"))
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login", "resources/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it! I put my css's in a css folder inside resources/static. And I used "/css/**" in the antMatchers section. Also href to the css should be: href="/css/design.css", my IDE has refactored it as href="../static/css/design.css" wich is WRONG, so look out for this! I hope it will help someone!